# Converting local transform to global transform

Tags: python, opencv, transformation

I'm using the following code to retrieve the local transforms from a depth map.

```
def reconstruct3d(depth_map, camera_parameters):
    transformation = np.identity(4)

    image_width, image_height = 320, 240

    inv_intr = np.linalg.inv(camera_parameters)

    for v in range(0, image_height, 1):
        for u in range(0, image_width, 1):
            projected_point = np.array([u, v, 1])
            image_point = np.matmul(inv_intr, projected_point)

            x, y = (image_point[0] / image_point[2]), (image_point[1] / image_point[2])

            depth = depth_map[v, u]

            Z = depth
            Y = Z * y
            X = Z * x

            transformed_point = np.matmul(transformation, np.array([X, Y, Z, 1]))
            transformed_point = transformed_point / transformed_point[3]
```

Unfortunately, the obtained `transformed_point` is in a local coordinate system. How can I convert it into a global coordinate system provided the fact that I know the camera parameters (both intrinsic and extrinsic camera parameters)?

Comment: please confirm, do you have the 4x4 pose matrix that describes the camera frame to world frame transformation? you can get that from "rvec" and "tvec" by expanding the rvec into a 3x3 matrix R, appending the tvec on the right side, and adding the fourth row.

Comment: yes, I have got the homogeneous matrix which is the 4x4 matrix that has both rvec and tvec

Comment: great! then multiply that with `np.array([x,y,z,1]).T` (or `np.append(the_point, 1).T`) which is the column vector of your point in the camera's frame of reference. I would suggest using `@` as an infix operator for numpy arrays, which is the dot product (matrix multiplication).

Comment: I have tried it but it is still the same. :( Should I multiple the column vector with the 4x4 matrix?

Comment: I used this code , `coord = np.array(coord).T
    pose = ext_mat @ coord`